# Is $\det(ABA ^{−1}) = \det B$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices with $A$ invertible. Prove that
$$\det (ABA^{−1}) = \det B$$

My Answer:

\begin{align}\det(ABA^{-1}) &= \det(B) \det (A)\det (A^{-1})\\
   &= \det(B) \det(A\cdot A^{-1})\\
   &=\det(B) \det(I_n)\\
   &=\det(BI_n)\\
   &=\det(B)\\
\end{align}

(The -1 is to the power -1 , i wasnt sure how to format it)

Comment: Your solution is correct!

Comment: formatting:  `$A^{-1}$` produces $A^{-1}$

Comment: The determinant map is a group homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$, which is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, recognize that $\det(A^{-1})=\frac1{\det(A)}$.

Hence $$\det(ABA^{-1})=\det(A)\det(B)\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)\det(B)\frac1{\det(A)}=\det(B).$$

Edit:

Since  $\det(A\cdot A^{-1})=\det(I_n)=1$ implies that $\det(A) \cdot \det(A^{-1})=1.$

Comment: OP would need to prove that $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)}$ first before using it.